# ADS1115 need negative power supply for negative Vin?

Tags: voltage, adc

I have a quick question because I don't fully understand the [ADS1115 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1114.pdf).

Do I need to put -0.2 V in the GND and 3 V in VDD to measure negative value in single-ended?

[image]

Comment: How negative can your input voltage get?

Comment: To measure voltages down to -0.2V, yes you'd need the IC's GND to be -0.2V too. That will mess up digital signals too, though, causing the I²C lines to go slightly negative, and have slightly shifted thresholds. Probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table 7.3 says the recommended Vin voltage stays above that on the ground pin. The absolute minimum (table 7.1) is GND-0.3, where you might expect the ESD diode to start conducting. You MIGHT get away with a lower input voltage, maybe down to -0.2 V, possibly with reduced accuracy, possibly with full accuracy, as the input measures differentially, and it's a switched capacitor architecture. If the switches operate properly below ground, then it will work to some extent. As it's advertised to work to ground, it's unlikely to stop operating completely as you go a little below ground, so there's some margin for you to explore.

A better solution would be to use an external amplifier, or a simpler resistive bias method, to shift your -0.2 V signal into the recommended input range for the converter.

It is easier, better, less likely to end in tears, to shift your signal up, than to shift the GND pin down.

Comment: Yeah, i see the table 7.1 but in 7.3 that recommand to don't go under GND voltage.

Comment: @DamanZ4 not "BUT in 7.3", but "AND in 7.3". Do you understand the difference between guaranteed working to specification, working a bit but possibly not to specification, and getting damaged? Try it and see. -0.2 V should not damage the IC, and it might work well enough for you. How well do you need it to work? Are you building one, or many? Do you want them all to work? If you don't want to try that, then see my second paragraph.

Comment: Okay, so i have to chose a voltage of -256mV as ground in differencial mode to have the  best utilisation of the ADS. I ll supply with 3V and -256mV and input AIN1 and AIN2 with my two sensor ouput after an amplifier (for the current).

Comment: Can i put the V- after amplifcation on the ads1115GND

Comment: I had a schematic in the post to well explain what i said

Comment: @DamanZ4 I'm not sure the schematic explains anything to me. There are so many ways to use the 1115 correctly, that putting the GND supply to other than GND seems silly. Try using a lower than GND input. If it doesn't work, then shift your signals so that they're in the recommended input range. There are several ways to use a diff-amp to present your sensor with no significant load, and to centre the output signal on a voltage of your choice. This seems to be an XY problem. The question should be 'how do I shift my signal'. Changing the GND voltage is the wrong answer, whatever the question.

Answer (score 1):

The ADC operates with a differential input. But AINP and AINN must each ride on a common mode voltage such that the inputs never exceed maximum range.

For single ended measurements, AINN must be grounded, so negative voltages on AINP are not possible.

Comment: SO i have to keep in differencial and not use an instrumentation amplifier

Comment: But I have to use an amplifier to replicate input voltage and don't ask to the sensor too much current.